# Average MySQL in new table

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have a database about weather that updates every second.
It contains temperature and wind speed.
This is my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table`.`test` (
`id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
`date` DATETIME() NOT NULL,
`temperature` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`wind_speed` INT(10) NOT NULL,
`humidity` FLOAT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
 ENGINE = InnoDB
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
 COLLATE = utf8_bin;
```

I need to find the average temperature every hour.
This is my code:

```
Select SELECT AVG( temperature ), date
FROM new_table
GROUP BY HOUR ( date )
```

My coding is working but the problem is that I want to move the value and date of the average to another table.
This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table.`table1` (
`idsea_state` INT(10) NOT NULL,
`dateavg` DATETIME() NOT NULL,
`avg_temperature` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`idsea_state`))
 ENGINE = InnoDB
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
 COLLATE = utf8_bin;
```

Is it possible? Can you give me the coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to insert new rows into a database based on data you have obtained from another table, you can do this by setting up an `INSERT` query targeting the destination table, then run a *sub-query* which will pull the data from the source table **and then the result set returned from the sub-query will be used to provide the VALUES used for the INSERT command**

Here is the basic structure, note that **the `VALUES` keyword is not used:**

```sql
INSERT INTO `table1`
(`dateavg`, `avg_temperature`) 
  SELECT `date` , avg(`temperature`)
  FROM   `test`;
```

Its also important to note that the **position of the columns returned by result set will be sequentially matched to its respective position in the INSERT fields of the outer query**

e.g. if you had a query

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (`foo`, `bar`, `baz`)
    SELECT (`a`, `y`, `g`) FROM table2
```

- `a` would be inserted into `foo`
- `y` would go into `bar`
- `g` would go into `baz`

due to their respective positions

---

I have made a working **demo** - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff740/4
I made the below changes to simplify the example and just demonstrate the concept involved.
Here is the DDL changes I made to your original code

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `temperature` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `wind_speed` INT(10),
  `humidity` FLOAT ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
 ENGINE = InnoDB
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
 COLLATE = utf8_bin;

 CREATE TABLE `table1` (
`idsea_state` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dateavg` VARCHAR(55),
`avg_temperature` VARCHAR(25),
 PRIMARY KEY (`idsea_state`))
 ENGINE = InnoDB
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
 COLLATE = utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO `test` 
(`date`,  `temperature`) VALUES
('2013-05-03', 7.5),
('2013-06-12', 17.5),
('2013-10-12', 37.5);

INSERT INTO `table1`
(`dateavg`, `avg_temperature`) 
  SELECT `date` , avg(`temperature`)
  FROM   `test`;
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works :) But I want this coding work run automatically every hour because my database receive data every second, should I use trigger or stored procedure?

Comment: I dont know that the answer to that question sorry. If it was me I would and I was running the DB on  a linux server, I would write a script in PHP that ran the query, and was triggered by a cron job - but thats just me whats best for you will probably be different. I recommend you ask another question and try and describe your DB, server environment etc with as much detail as possible and someone else might have an answer